# Run many AutoIt script files using a main file (XML, Java, AutoIt or any language)

Tags: autoit

I'm using [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) for testing my application. There are different test cases for that. I will create these test cases as au3 files. Now I want to run all these scripts one after other. That is, a main script which call all sub script files one after other. How can I do that?

Comment: Just create a master AutoIt program and have this program run all the sub programs. No need for Java to do this, and I'm not sure what this has to do with XML.

Answer (score 2):

In a main AutoIt script (***main.au3***) you just add:

```vb
#include <UDF_function_1.au3>
#include <UDF_function_2.au3>
#include <UDF_function_3.au3>

Func _lanch_all()
    ; In order to run AutoIt function
    _function_1() ; from UDF_function_1.au3
    _function_2() ; from UDF_function_2.au3
    _function_3() ; from UDF_function_3.au3

    Run(PATH_to_script\"script_1.bat") ; In order to run a batch script windows
    Run(PATH_to_executable\"script_2.exe") ; In order to run an executable
EndFunc
```

And for example ***UDF_function_1.au3*** contains:

```vb
#include-once
Func _function_1()
    ConsoleWrite("Call of _function_1"&@CRLF)
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to compile these test cases, you just compile the main exe:

Compiled.exe [/ErrorStdOut] [/AutoIt3ExecuteScript file] [params ...]
                Execute another script file from a compiled AutoIt3 Script File. Then you don't need to fileinstall another copy of AutoIT3.exe in your compiled file.

```
#include <File.au3>

$Path = @ScriptDir & 'TestCases\'
$files = _FileListToArray($Path, "*.au3")

For $i = 1 To $files[0]
    RunWait(@ScriptFullPath & '/AutoIt3ExecuteScript "' & $Path & $files[$i] & '.au3"')
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a master AutoIt program and have this program run the other sub programs. If they are present in .au3 format, simply have the master program **include** the sub programs via the `include` keyword:

```
#include "[path\]filename"
```

This will allow the master program to call functions of the included sub-program.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <File.au3>

$Path = @ScriptDir & 'TestCases\'
$files = _FileListToArray($Path, "*.au3")

For $i = 1 To $files[0]
    RunWait(@ScriptFullPath & '/AutoIt3ExecuteScript "' & $Path & $files[$i] & '.au3"')
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

modified code as follows:

```
#include <File.au3>
$Path = @ScriptDir & '\TestCases\'
$files = _FileListToArray($Path, "*.au3")
MsgBox(0,"path", $files[0])
For $i = 1 To $files[0]
    RunWait(@AutoItExe & " /AutoIt3ExecuteScript "& '"'& $Path & $files[$i] & '"')
Next
```